# Cannot remove desktop files from .config/autostart folder

Tags: arch-linux, lxde, .desktop, autostart

I am configuring a arch based machine with a minimal desktop setup. I am logging into a qtile session, and I have the 'lxsession' package installed and run on start, but I am not logged into an lxde session.

My problem is that I have some desktop files that keep appearing in `~/.config/autostart` and I do not understand why.

There is no autostart folder in `~/.config/lxsessions`, there is no `/etc/xdg/LXDE` folder and nothing related to autostart in `/usr/share/lxsessions`.

I keep deleting the `.config/autostart` folder contents, everything is disabled on the `lxsession` gui setting app for autostart, but on each reboot the desktop files are back.

Does anyone have an idea of why that could be ?

Comment: Does `qtile` have an autostart?  I just checked the [documentation](https://docs.qtile.org/en/stable/index.html) and couldn't find one, but I'm no user either.  Are you sure that the `lxsession` isn't triggering LXDE to autostart?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the interest. qtile has a hook that can be used to trigger arbitrary python functions, it can be found in the 'built-in hools' section of the doc. For the second question, I am not sure how to check that. I never installed Lxde, only the `lxsession` package, as far as I researched, I have no folder in /usr/ or in xdg_config usually associated with the LXDE desktop. Finally, I have no lxde X11 sessions configured. I am not very familiar with lxde, or lxsession, this is the first time I use it.

Comment: [LXDE](https://www.lxde.org/) is the Desktop Environment.  LX Session is the Session Manager.  I believe LX Session triggers LXDE by default. If I Remember Correctly, it's  related to XFCE in some way.

Comment: Thanks, I have no package installed related to lxde except lxsessions. `yay -Qs lxde` returns nothing. As I mentioned before there are none of the folders usually associated with lxde on my system. So I do not think lxde is the problem here. I do not know how to investigate further. Can I find out which process creates the desktop files somehow ? Maybe analysing the logs...

Comment: I found the begining of an explanation on lxsession's github page. There is a section about autostart, and tweaking the config file I already managed to stop the undesired behavior of recreating desktop files in the `.config/autostart` folder. The applications are still being autostarted though. I am not sure I will have the opportunity to do much more testing today, but I'll report back soon.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could read from the arch wiki pages dedicated to autostarting applications and the lxsession github page, I do not think lxsession was responsible for this annoyance.

I tried all settings in lxsession designed to control autostart with no effects, I also tried creating an autostart file in the lxsession config folder, this does not work either. Settings from lxsession gui utilities have no effect on autostart, or config files.

From what I could glean on various forums, the apps themselves are responsible for creating those dektop files in the autostart folders. And removing the files does not always work because some app are known to recreate autostart desktop files automatically.

**Finally, I could regain control over application autostart by placing a desktop entry in the local autostart folder with an entry `Hidden=true` as recommended by the arch wiki.** This solution works pretty well so far and solves the "auto re-creation" of desktop files issue.

The only thing I do not completely understand is why lxsession executes the desktop files in the autostart folders, but no configuration settings I tried had any effect.